# HTML forms in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, html

Hello all how to use HTML text field instead of ASP.NET textbox.?

How to write C# code to make use of HTML forms instead of ASP.NET

Comment: would be better to specify exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <input id="Text1" type="text" runat="server" />

    <asp:Button ID="Button5"
        runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="button5_click" />
    <div>


        <script runat="server">
            protected void button5_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Text1.Value = "Hello";
            }
        </script>


</form>
```

Comment: Well... I do know this but how to write a code in C# to display hello world in the HTML textbox while I make a click on HTML submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using  or whatever server control, just type in the standard  type tags or whichever HTML control you want.

If you want to be able to access them from your code-behind, then just include a runat="server" value with each HTML tag and make sure you give it an ID.

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the value from the HTTP request's `Form` collection:

```
<input type="text" name="MyTextField" />
```

Code behind:

```
string value = Request.Form["MyTextField"];
```

Comment: Thanks, this what I am waiting for but can I use the behind code in C# file?

Answer (score 0):

This question doesn't make much sense. You really should clarify and flesh out the question and explain what you are trying to do.

In some ways, an ASP.NET textbox *is* an HTML text field that C# code can make use of. So what's the problem with an ASP.NET textbox?

Comment: yeah... but while I'm compiling ASP.NET forms in .csproj file I'm getting an error with error code of CS0103 So, I prefer to make use of HTML forms instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an instance of a HtmlInput control in code, or alternatively add a runat="server" attribute to an <input> element in your aspx file, you can then access this from server-side code using it's ID.

As an alternative, you may wish to take a look at http://asp.net/mvc to get better control of your HTML markup.